# Marklogic XCC cannot commit without an active transaction

Tags: java, marklogic

I am having an issue with mark logic.I am using the XCC/J api. I have a multi-statment transaction and i am doing something like below.

```
Session sess = ContentSource.newSession();
sess.setTransactionMode(TransactionMode.UPDATE)
....Perform some queries.....
session.commit();
```

But i keep getting 
IllegalStateException cannot commit without an active transaction

Comment: Edit your code sample so that it's a working test case that reproduces the problem. As is it won't parse: the variable `sess` changes to `session`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Application Developer's Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_20593):

> To start a transaction and obtain a Transaction object, call the openTransaction() method on a DatabaseClient object (since the transaction controls if database changes are made). To call openTransaction(), an application must authenticate as rest-writer or rest-admin.

```
Transaction transaction = client.openTransaction();
```

Looks like you don't have that in your sample code, so I think you just missed the step of starting the transaction.

Comment: Doh, sorry. Just re-read and saw you're using XCC. What I posted above is for the Java Client API.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another commit or rollback elsewhere in your code that's called before that commit.

You might have multiple sessions open, and the one you're trying to commit isn't a multi-statement transaction.

It's also worth checking for updates to the XCC jars and the server.